# Rshiny : selectInput in modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny

I want to open a modalDialog containing a selectInput list and a textAreaInput. This modalDialog is inside an observeEvent and is well displayed when the event is triggered.

When the modalDialog pop, the user choose an item in the list (a month's name). I want the choosed month to be displayed in the textAreaInput.

I tested this piece of code but the value `input$dateList` of the `selectInput` is not displayed in the textAreaInput.

Any clue ? Thanx a lot !

```
dates = c("january","february","march") 
showModal(modalDialog(
    output$date_input <- renderUI({ 
        selectInput("dateList",  "History:",choices=c(dates))
    }),  
    textAreaInput(width=600, "test", "test", value=input$dateList),
    footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"), actionButton("Ok", "OK))
))
```

---

## EDIT (by @SL)

Reproductible code (does not work):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input[["open"]], {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tagList(
        selectInput(
          "dateList", "History:", 
          choices = c("january", "february", "march")
        ),
        textAreaInput(width = 600, "test", "test", value = input[["dateList"]])
      ),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"), actionButton("Ok", "OK"))
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That can't work like this but there's surely a JavaScript solution. Actually it would be simpler to help if you told us why do you want to do that exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `updateTextAreaInput` inside `observeEvent`.

```
  observeEvent(input[["dateList"]], {
    updateTextAreaInput(inputId = "test", value = input$dateList)
  })
```

App
Thanks @StéphaneLaurent for providing reproducible code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("open", "Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input[["open"]], {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tagList(
        selectInput(
          "dateList", "History:",
          choices = c("january", "february", "march")
        ),
        textAreaInput(width = 600, "test", "test")
      ),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"), actionButton("Ok", "OK"))
    ))
  })

  observeEvent(input[["dateList"]], {
    updateTextAreaInput(inputId = "test", value = input$dateList)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I had issue because my environment was more complex than the given example but your answer helped me to understand